# Localizing labels in org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker

Tags: java, localization, yui, datepicker, wicket

Does anyone know how to localize the "Month", "Year", "Okay" and "Cancel" labels of the org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker?

According to the API you can override the the localize(Map) method to set up localized Strings, but i failed to find out what the names of the corresponding properties are.

Comment: No clear solution, just added a list of links for you to explore...

Comment: Looking through the source of DatePicker it seems like at least Month/Year labels are tied to Component's locale setting.  Beyond that I'm not sure where the other labels do come from.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calnavigator.html) you may localize the labels by overriding the configure method of the DatePicker class:

```
    public class DatePicker extends org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker {

    @Override
    protected void configure(Map<String, Object> widgetProperties) {
        super.configure(widgetProperties);

        /*
        * var navConfig = {
        *   strings: {
        *   month:"Calendar Month",
        *   year:"Calendar Year",
        *   submit: "Submit",
        *   cancel: "Cancel",
        *   invalidYear: "Please enter a valid year"
        *   },
        * monthFormat: YAHOO.widget.Calendar.SHORT,
        * initialFocus: "month"
        * }
        */

        Map<String, Object> strings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        strings.put("month", "Месяц");
        strings.put("year", "Год");
        strings.put("submit", "Ok"); // put label for 'Okay' button
        strings.put("cancel", "Отмена"); // put label for 'Cancel' button
        strings.put("invalidYear", "Введите корректный год");

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("strings", strings); // pass localization related parameters
        props.put("monthFormat", "YAHOO.widget.Calendar.SHORT");
        props.put("initialFocus", "year");

        widgetProperties.put("navigator", props);
    }
}
```

Hope you'll find this code snippet useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [ticket 754](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-754) add support for [localization](http://chillenious.wordpress.com/2007/07/29/yuis-datepicker-from-wicket-datetime-localized/).

May be the [patch introduced then](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12361861/datetime-localization.patch) can give you some clues? It references:

```
src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/locale/DatePicker_de.properties
```

with:

```
DATE_FIELD_DELIMITER=x
MDY_DAY_POSITION=1
MDY_MONTH_POSITION=2
MDY_YEAR_POSITION=3
MD_DAY_POSITION=1
MD_MONTH_POSITION=2

MONTHS_SHORT=Jan,Feb,M\u00E4r,Apr,Mai,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Okt,Nov,Dez

MONTHS_LONG=Januar,Februar,M\u00E4rz,April,Mai,Juni,Juli,August,September,Oktober,November,Dezember
WEEKDAYS_1CHAR=S,M,D,M,D,F,S
WEEKDAYS_SHORT=So,Mo,Di,Mi,Do,Fr,Sa
WEEKDAYS_MEDIUM=Son,Mon,Die,Mit,Don,Fre,Sam
WEEKDAYS_LONG=Sonntag,Montag,Dienstag,Mittwoch,Donnerstag,Freitag,Samstag
```

---

Regarding the localization of the *labels* itself, may be you could try:

- [getResourceSettings()](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/wicket-1.3.2/wicket/apidocs/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getResourceSettings()) mentioned in ["Everything about Wicket internationalization"](http://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/everything-about-wicket-internationalization.html)
- a similar approach than [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@wicket.apache.org/msg32736.html) (which was for another component)
- check the dateTimePicker code in [this page](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket13/dates/)
- check out the [project Wicket-Calendar](http://wicket-stuff.svn.sf.net/svnroot/wicket-stuff/trunk/wicket-calendar/) and see if there is not clues in the code itself
- check out [JSCalendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) upon which [DatePicker seems to be based](http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/wicket-contrib-datepicker).

Comment: That allows for localization of the actual months and week days. What i'm looking for is localization for the labels "Month", "Year", "Okay" and "Cancel" (the latter 2 are button labels).

Comment: @tehvan: "What I'm looking for is localization for the labels"... which you did already told me in your previous comment! Sorry about that. Still looking for the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the labels on the calendar navigator. This [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calnavigator.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is nice:

```
protected static final String[] NAVIGATOR_LOCALIZATION_KEYS = {
    "month", "year", "submit", "cancel", "invalidYear",
};

In overridden method u should write: 

super.configure(widgetProperties, response, initVariables);
    Map<String, String> strings = MapBuilder.newHashMap();
    for (String key : NAVIGATOR_LOCALIZATION_KEYS) {
        strings.put(key, LocalizationUtils.getString(key));
    }
    widgetProperties.put(
        "navigator", Collections.singletonMap("strings", strings)
    );
```